# Can the Government hold a vote of confidence in themselves with the intention of losing?

Tags: united-kingdom, election

Borris Johnson has [failed to get an early election](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-49584907). However, I’m aware that a vote of no confidence in the government would also lead to a general election if no other party could win a vote (which seems unlikely):

[image]

<sup>Third image in [this BBC News article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-46393399)</sup>

Can the government call a vote of confidence which they intend to lose, and then have that election?

Comment: It did work that way in Germany in 2005. But I am not familiar with the UK system to know if it also applies there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they could.

Whether this is a good idea is debatable, (consider them trying to campaign when they have effectivly said that they have no confidence in themselves) but they could trigger a vote.

Comment: I’d vaguely guess than not many people would know or care why there was an election - they’d vote along Brexit line again. But a fair point.

Comment: But there is the Brexit Party etc. that would need to be fought off, and internal rivals who could use it down the line.

Comment: As a piece of possible pedantry, it might be worth being clear that this would (probably) have to be a literal vote of no confidence in themselves. The FTPA actually specifies the wording of the necessary motion as "That this House has no confidence in Her Majesty’s Government." http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2011/14/section/2/enacted

Comment: My favourite bit is you could in theory have the government voting for the motion and the opposition against, with the government's inability to win a vote gaining them the confidence of the house... :Shrug:

Comment: @Orangesandlemons in a slightly sadistic way, I’m sort of hoping this is what happens. I imagine it would be one of very few, or only, times where a government wins a vote of confidence and didn’t want to.